# Creating a new ManagedBuffer in Rust tests panics "called Option::unwrap() on a None"

Tags: rust, multiversx

I'm trying to create a new `ManagedBuffer` in a rust test, but the tests panic. I've tried using both, the `ManagedBuffer::new_from_bytes` function and the `managed_buffer!` macro, but both of them result in the same error:

> thread 'use_managed_buffer_new_from_bytes' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /home/mccuna/elrondsdk/vendor-rust/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/elrond-wasm-debug-0.27.4/src/tx_mock/tx_context_stack.rs:16:28

> thread 'use_managed_buffer_macro' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /home/mccuna/elrondsdk/vendor-rust/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/elrond-wasm-debug-0.27.4/src/tx_mock/tx_context_stack.rs:16:28

```rs
// test_test.rs
use elrond_wasm::types::ManagedBuffer;
use elrond_wasm_debug::{managed_buffer, tx_mock::TxContextRef};

#[test]
fn use_managed_buffer_macro() {
  let test: ManagedBuffer<TxContextRef> = managed_buffer!(b"Test");
}

#[test]
fn use_managed_buffer_new_from_bytes() {
  let test = ManagedBuffer::<TxContextRef>::new_from_bytes(b"Test");
}
```

Versions used:

```
[dependencies.elrond-wasm]
version = "0.27.4"

[dev-dependencies.elrond-wasm-debug]
version = "0.27.4"
```

Comment: I think it is similar to the issue I got here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129135/print-is-failing-in-execute-query-whereas-it-works-out-of-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close to the end of [this docs section](https://docs.elrond.com/developers/developer-reference/rust-testing-framework/#writing-your-first-test) it's mentioned that "Keep in mind you can't create managed types outside of the execute_tx functions. If you need to do that, you should use `blockchain_wrapper.execute_in_managed_environment()`"

So, the default solution to creating a `ManagedBuffer` from bytes is to make the call inside a `blockchain_wrapper.execute_in_managed_environment()` closure.

An alternative to `blockchain_wrapper.execute_in_managed_environment()` is to call `let _ = DebugApi::dummy();` before calling `ManagedBuffer::new_from_bytes`. `DebugApi::dummy()` instantiates the required mocks for the `ManagedBuffer::new_from_bytes` to work in Rust tests.

P.s.: `DebugApi::dummy()` works with static fields. I've not checked but calling it multiple times might result in issues
P.p.s: thank you Martin!