# print!() is failing in execute_query whereas it works out of it

Tags: multiversx

I am doing some rust tests in the elrond blockchain.

When I print a token identifier outside of execute_query, my token is well printed. Whereas, it throws an error when I try to print it in the execute_query.

```rust
#[test]
fn test_foo() {
    let mut setup = utils::setup(equip_penguin::contract_obj);

    let token = TokenIdentifier::<DebugApi>::from_esdt_bytes(b"ITEM-a1a1a1");
    // works
    println!("{:x?}", token);

    let b_wrapper = &mut setup.blockchain_wrapper;

    let _ = b_wrapper.execute_query(&setup.cf_wrapper, |sc| {
        // throw errors
        println!("{:x?}", token);
    });
}
```

The error is

```
thread 'build_url_with_one_item' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /home/username/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/elrond-wasm-debug-0.27.4/src/tx_mock/tx_managed_types.rs:38:31
```

The utils::setup used in the above snippet code from this doc https://docs.elrond.com/developers/developer-reference/rust-testing-framework/

How does this error happens?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, managed types must be declared inside `execute_query`.

The above code works:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_foo() {
    let mut setup = utils::setup(equip_penguin::contract_obj);

    let b_wrapper = &mut setup.blockchain_wrapper;

    let _ = b_wrapper.execute_query(&setup.cf_wrapper, |sc| {
        let token = TokenIdentifier::<DebugApi>::from_esdt_bytes(b"ITEM-a1a1a1");
        println!("{:x?}", token);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you found the part about being declared inside `execute_query` in some docs, or just by trial & error? I'm asking because I need that `ManagedBuffer` as an `out_val` of a `TxEpectMandos` so I don't have access to a closure (I'm generating a Mandos test using Rust, similar to [this](https://docs.elrond.com/developers/developer-reference/rust-testing-framework/#testing-queries)). I'm new to Elrond so I'm not sure if it's a problem in my mental model of how tests should look, or a bug in `elrond-wasm`.

Comment: Ok, after some more digging, I found the docs part mentioning [this](https://docs.elrond.com/developers/developer-reference/rust-testing-framework/#writing-your-first-test) (it's close to the end of this section).

It seems that indeed, a managed type should be created either by using `blockchain_wrapper.execute_in_managed_environment()` or by calling `let _ = DebugApi::dummy();` to initialize the `DebugApi`. P.s.: thank you Martin!